# jQuery search element change

Tags: jquery

I need help changing equals mark to slash
as in now, when I submit my form, url it gets me is **#search=x** but I need it to be **#search/x**

```
<form name="input" action="" method="get">
Search: <input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('form').submit(function() {
var form_data = ($(this).serialize());
window.location = "#" + form_data;
return false;
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: You know you could do this with just a regular anchor `<a href="#search/x">Do search</a>`, right? There's no need for a form to change a hash!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that easy with native replace method:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    window.location = "#" + form_data.replace("=", "/");
    return false;
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ohulaz/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
data = form_data.replace('=', '/');
```

As for your second question use:

```
window.location.hash = form_data;
```

That should overwrite the previous if I understood the problem correctly.

Whole thing:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var form_data = ($(this).serialize());
    window.location.hash = form_data.replace('=','/');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It did work. Also one more thing maybe you can help me with. When I search something else, it shows Result: testResult: test2